# Find numpy array values bounding an input value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a value, say 2016 and a sorted numpy array: `[2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030]`. What is the pythonic way to find the 2 values in the array that bound 2016. In this case, the answer will be an array [2015, 2020].

Not sure how to do it other than loop, but hoping for a more numpy based solution

--EDIT:

you can assume that you will never get a value that is in the array, I prefilter for that

Comment: Is the array known to be sorted when you start, or could it be in random order? Your example shows a sorted array.

Comment: yes, the array can be assumed to be sorted

Comment: What would the correct answer be if the array is the same but the value is 2015? Would it be [2010, 2020], or [2015, 2020], or [2010, 2015], or even just [2015, 2015] ?

Comment: you can assume that you will never get a value that is in the array, I prefilter for that. Thanks for the question, will update question to reflect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
In[1]: import numpy as np

In[2]: x = np.array([2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030])

In[3]: x
Out[3]: array([2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030])


In[4]: x[x > 2016].min()
Out[4]: 2020


In[5]: x[x < 2016].max()
Out[5]: 2015

In[6]: def bound(value, arr):
           return arr[arr < value].max(), arr[arr > value].min()

In[7]: bound(2016, x)
Out[7]: (2015, 2020)
```

Answer (score 5):

A straight-forward approach would be with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(A,B,'left')
out = A[idx],A[idx+1]
```

**Explanation**

The inputs are -

```
In [27]: A
Out[27]: [2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030]

In [28]: B
Out[28]: 2015
```

Find the index where B should sit in A to maintain the sorted nature with `searchsorted`. This would correspond to the lower bound index. So, index into `A` with `index` and `index+1` for the two bounding values -

```
In [29]: idx = np.searchsorted(A,B,'left')

In [30]: idx
Out[30]: 2

In [31]: A[idx],A[idx+1]
Out[31]: (2015, 2020)
```

Comment: This solution is logarithmic (while others take linear time) and should be an accepted answer.